# Finding a given element in nested iframes *recursively*

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What's the best possible way to find a given "div.myClass" element in the current document, as well as any iframes it (and their nested iframes, too) might have?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided that frame access is not restricted by the same origin policy:

```
function getElem(selector, $root, $collection) {
    if (!$root) $root = $(document);
    if (!$collection) $collection = $();
    // Select all elements matching the selector under the root
    $collection = $collection.add($root.find(selector));
    // Loop through all frames
    $root.find('iframe,frame').each(function() {
        // Recursively call the function, setting "$root" to the frame's document
        getElem(selector, $(this).contents(), $collection);
    });
    return $collection;
}
// Example:
var $allImageElements = getElem('img');
```