# Recursively locate element within nested iframes

Tags: javascript

My goal is to select an element regardless of where it is located inside a chain of nested iframes.

I am basically looking for a vanilla javascript equivalent of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11224815/1737287

Comment: whats wrong with the example you've sent?

Comment: @AlexShtromberg it's using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not be able to search for an iframe within an iframe without changing the document's "context" using something like

```
iframe.contentDocument
```

method. You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument)

In your case, you need to grab all of the iframes recursively as you reset the contentDocument as needed. Something similar to this may work for your purposes

```
function getAllIframes() {
            let allIframes = [];
            let topLevelIframes  = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            for (let i = 0; i < topLevelIframes.length;i++) {
                    console.log(topLevelIframes[i])
                    traverseDeeperIntoIframes(topLevelIframes[i])
            }
            function traverseDeeperIntoIframes(ctx) {
                allIframes.push(ctx)
                // Fallback for contentWindow
                const iframeContext = (ctx.contentDocument) ? ctx.contentDocument : ctx.contentWindow.document
                const tmpFrames = iframeContext.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
                console.log(iframeContext, tmpFrames)

                for (let i = 0; i < tmpFrames.length;i++) {
                    traverseDeeperIntoIframes(tmpFrames[i])
                }
            }
            return allIframes;
} 

        const allIframes = getAllIframes()

        // Iterate over this allIframes <Array> resetting the contentWindow at every context.
        // For example 
        function queryOverAllContentWindows(allIframes, cb) {
            for (let i = 0; i < allIframes.length;i++) {
                const ctx = (allIframes[i].contentDocument) ? allIframes[i].contentDocument : allIframes[i].contentWindow.document

                // Pass the iframe context into any arbitrary callback
                cb(ctx)
            }
        }
```